# How to visualize a hierarchical clustering as a tree of labelled nodes in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, clustering, visualization

The chapter ["Normalized Information Distance"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2553), visualizes a hierarchical clustering as a tree of nodes with labels:
[image: Hierarchical Clustering visualization from "Normalized Information Distance"]

Unfortunately I cannot find out how to replicate this visualization, maybe they did it in a manual way with Tikz?
How can I achieve this effect automatically in Python, preferably with Scikit-Learn? I only found the Dendogram, which looks nothing like the effect I want to replicate:

[image]

## Result (thanks at @andy-w):

```
model = AgglomerativeClustering(linkage="average", n_clusters=N_CLUSTERS, compute_distances=True, affinity="l1")
model.fit(data)
no_of_observations = np.arange(2, model.children_.shape[0]+2)
linkage_matrix = np.column_stack([model.children_, model.distances_, no_of_observations]).astype(float)

G = nx.Graph()    
n = len(linkage_matrix)
for i in range(n):
    row = linkage_matrix[i]
    G.add_edge(label(int(row[0])),label(n+i+1),len=1+0.1*(math.log(1+row[2])))  
    G.add_edge(label(int(row[1])),label(n+i+1),len=1+0.1*(math.log(1+row[2])))  

dot = nx.nx_pydot.to_pydot(G).to_string()
dot = graphviz.Source(dot, engine='neato')
dot.render(format='pdf',filename='tree')
```

[image: result so far]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific format to me looks like [graphviz](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/). So if you can extract the tree edges from your original object, then you can render it, example below (some roundabout to convert between different objects):

```
import networkx as nx
import pydot
import graphviz

# Just a part of your graph
G = nx.Graph()
ed = [('n3','n0'),
      ('n0','MusicHendrixA'),
      ('n0','MusicHendrixB'),
      ('n3','n2'),
      ('n2','n8'),
      ('n8','MusicBergA'),
      ('n8','MusicBergB') ]
G.add_edges_from(ed)

# Now the graphviz part
dot = nx.nx_pydot.to_pydot(G).to_string()
dot = graphviz.Source(dot, engine='neato')
dot.render(format='png',filename='MusicTree')
```

[image: GraphViz Output Neato]

Comment: The part on how to draw a graph is very helpful, however my main problem is the conversion itself. However I got some pointers in that direction at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838861/scipy-linkage-format.

Comment: Nice job @KonradHöffner! (Agree when I looked at the internals figuring out the nodes/edges was not straightforward.)